# my workaround is to have for each button a JavaScript to be able to open the specific .modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, parameters, modal-dialog, parameter-passing

I'm using SVG Image Map.
The shapes "circle" inside  are formatted as button by css.

So, clicked it opens  nested Text and images in a Modal (Bootstrap)

As I have several hotspots i should open specific Modal.
as a workaround I put own JavaScript for each modal (myBtn1, myBtn2 etc.) Content. Trying to fix a JavaScript for that I discover many unknowns. Like javascript:void(0), or eval() in another example.

so I would like to use something like that, to put the Modals Content in the HTML Part and define Variables for them to use with something like in the approach below to show the modal according the clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/6v3gkq1t/

```
<body>
<div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
Text Text IMAGE Text
    </div>
<!--<a href="#" onclick="data();">Logout</a>-->
        </body>
```

In JavaScript:

```
window.data = function(){
    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML;
    alert(MyDiv1);
    };
```

As an aproach I was looking at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ub8wz5Lb/

HTML:

```
<div id="parentblock">
  <h5>Contacts List</h5>
    <div class="switchMeOut">
    </div>
</div>

<button data-id="firstHTML" class="swapper first">Shows First Only </button>
 <button data-id="secondHTML" class="swapper second">Shows Second Only </button>
 <button data-id="thirdHTML" class="swapper third">Shows Third Only </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var firstHTML = '<div class="switchMeOut"><p>First Section Content</div>';
var secondHTML = '<div class="switchMeOut"><p>Second Section Content</div>';
var thirdHTML = '<div class="switchMeOut"><p>Third Section Content</div>'; 

$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var content = eval(id);
  $('div.switchMeOut').html(content);
});
$('div.switchMeOut').html(firstHTML + secondHTML + thirdHTML);
});
```

I'm using this javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script>
```

the html look like this:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1690 720" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g id="Ebene_5">
    <circle class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn" cx="505.1" cy="222.1" r="7.5"/>
</g>
</svg>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="button">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  var firstmodal = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>';

</div>javascript:void(0);`
```